# Simple Javascript DOM Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am learning about how to incorporate Javascript into Objective-C applications on the Mac. I know some very basic HTML and a very minuscule amount of Javascript. Apple's WebKit DOM Programming Guide outlines some simple uses of Javascript and DOM, but I can't get this example code to work:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Sample HTML file</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 var parasDiv = document.getElementById("allMyParas");
 var thirdPara = document.createElement("p");
 thirdPara.setAttribute("id", "thirdParagraph");
 parasDiv.appendChild(thirdPara);
 thirdPara.innerHTML = "This is my third paragraph.";
 parasDiv.style.borderBottom = "1px #000 solid";
 var parasInDiv = parasDiv.getElementsByTagName("p");
 for (var i = 0; i < parasInDiv.length; i++) {
  parasInDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";

 }

   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="allMyParas" style="border-top: 1px #000 solid;">
<p id="firstParagraph">
    This is my first paragraph.
</p>
<p id="secondParagraph">
    This is my second paragraph.
</p>
```

The result is a black line at the top of my browser and the two original paragraphs, but not the third that should have been created.

I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. They yield the same results?

Could anyone explain why Apple's example code doesn't work?

Comment: Showing your C code might be helpful too

Comment: [It works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/5tGFC/). Did you check your browser's error console?

Comment: @TimWolla try it now http://jsfiddle.net/5tGFC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executed before the `allMyParas` div or any of the elements you try to lookup is created.
You can put your code at the bottom of the body to ensure the elements you try to access is created.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Sample HTML file</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="allMyParas" style="border-top: 1px #000 solid;">
<p id="firstParagraph">
    This is my first paragraph.
</p>
<p id="secondParagraph">
    This is my second paragraph.
</p>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 var parasDiv = document.getElementById("allMyParas");
 var thirdPara = document.createElement("p");
 thirdPara.setAttribute("id", "thirdParagraph");
 parasDiv.appendChild(thirdPara);
 thirdPara.innerHTML = "This is my third paragraph.";
 parasDiv.style.borderBottom = "1px #000 solid";
 var parasInDiv = parasDiv.getElementsByTagName("p");
 for (var i = 0; i < parasInDiv.length; i++) {
  parasInDiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";

 }

</script>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Why is it recommended to put Javascript code in <head>, then? Is that outdated advice?

Comment: @Blakeasd Is it? I've never heard that.