# Audio isn't playing for my alarm clock. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

My audio isn't playing when my alarm is supposed to turn on. I've got the url of the code and the id as well, but the audio isn't playing even when I made it to play when the timer goes off. What's wrong with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src='script.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
.time { 
    background-color:#000;
    border:#026efc 4px inset;
    padding:6px;
    color:#0FF;
    font-family:"Silom";
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    display:inline;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var set=0;
var audio = document.getElementById('BGSOUND_ID');
ver=parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
ie4=(ver>3  && navigator.appName!="Netscape")?1:0;
function play() {
    if (ie4) 
        document.all['BGSOUND_ID'].src="http://hopto.redirectme.net/Audio/Alarm%20Beeps.mp3";
        document.getElementById('BGSOUND_ID').play();
}
function setv() {
    var hr2    = document.getElementById('hour2').value;
    var min2   = document.getElementById('min2').value;
    var sec2   = document.getElementById('sec2').value;
    if(hr2<10)
        hr2='0'+hr2;
    if(min2<10)
        min2='0'+min2;
    if(sec2<10)
        sec2='0'+sec2;
    document.getElementById('d2').value=hr2+'*'+min2+'*'+sec2;
    set=1;
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Alarm is ON';
}
function dis() {
    var dat= new Date();
    var hr=dat.getHours();
    var min=dat.getMinutes();
    var sec=dat.getSeconds();
    if(hr<10)
        hr='0'+hr;
    if(min<10)
        min='0'+min;
    if(sec<10)
        sec='0'+sec;
    document.getElementById('hour').value=hr;
    document.getElementById('min').value=min;
    document.getElementById('sec').value=sec; 
    var dat2v=document.getElementById('d2').value;
    var dats =hr+'*'+min+'*'+sec;
    if(dat2v==dats && set) {
        play();
        var x = confirm("Snooze?");
        if(x) {
            document.getElementById('BGSOUND_ID').pause();
            audio.currentTime=0;
        }
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Alarm is OFF';
        set=0;
    }
    setTimeout("dis()",500);
}
function prtsel(x) {
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
    document.write("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table align=center width=45%>
<tr><td>
<body onload=dis()>
<audio id="BGSOUND_ID" src="http://hopto.redirectme.net/Audio/Alarm%20Beeps.mp3/" LOOP=1>
</audio>
<input type=hidden id=d2 name=d2>
<input type=text id=hour name=hour size=1 class=time> :
<input type=text id=min name=min size=1 class=time> :
<input type=text id=sec name=sec size=1 class=time>
<br/>
<select id=hour2 name=hour2 onChange="setv()">
<script type='text/javascript'>prtsel(25);</script>
</select>
<select id=min2 name=min2 onChange="setv()">
<script type='text/javascript'>prtsel(61);</script>
</select>
<select id=sec2 name=sec2 onChange="setv()">
<script type='text/javascript'>prtsel(61);</script>
</select>
<div id=msg>Alarm is OFF</div>
</body>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418435/simple-javascript-dom-example-not-working

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but why are you browser-detecting IE4? [Here's a list of browsers that support `audio` elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio). Writing IE4-specific code to assign the source of an HTML5 audio element is the anachronistic equivalent of translating the W3C HTML spec into old Norse.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the source of the Audio tag. The URL should follow this format: `protocol://host/path`. Your Audio's source ends in a slash, indicating a subdirectory. If you were to look at your browser's network tab, you would see a request that fails.
The markup for the source of the audio tag is also (in my opinion) improperly formatted.
It should look as follows:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://hopto.redirectme.net/Audio/Alarm%20Beeps.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

This allows you to specify multiple sources, and hence let the browser decide which it would like to play, depending on which it supports best...

In addition, the variable `audio` is evaluating to null, because the audio element has not yet been rendered when the code executes. Hence, you can shift the script to after the HTML markup or only setup the variable when the body loads, in your `dis()` function.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually the markup for the `audio` is not wrong, it's legal to specify the source through the `src` attribute. It's not legal to combine a `src` attribute and a child `source` element, of course.

Comment: @Jeremy - Of course, you are right. It is my opinion that this is good semantics though, for example when you would like to specify multiple sources! Thanks for pointing it out though - it is valid HTML and will work if the browser supports mp3 audio. I have updated my answer to show this.